# How can I auto-format a Python file that contains long strings to pass when I run flake8?

Tags: python, formatting, pep8, flake8

I have a lot of json style data that I am storing for some unit test api mocking I am working on. The data is stored in a .py file in the form of a Python dictionary, I didn't write it so I had no control over the line length when it was created.

I am now under going code review and this file is failing flake8 because some of the lines are +1000 chars. I've tried `autopep8`, `pep8` and `black`, I've tried changing the line wrap in VS Code and I've tried searching for an answer online but am not getting anywhere.

Is there a way of auto formatting this kind of file because doing it manually will take ages and be very tedious. Thanks

EDIT

I have this config in my `settings.json`

```
{
  "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\andre_2d8wovo\\.virtualenvs\\asana_data-LIIUPrbn\\Scripts\\python.exe",
  "editor.detectIndentation": false,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.insertSpaces": true,
  "editor.tabSize": 4,
  "python.formatting.autopep8Args": ["--max-line-length=80"],
  "python.formatting.provider": "autopep8",
  "python.linting.enabled": true,
  "python.linting.lintOnSave": true,
  "python.linting.pycodestyleArgs": ["--max-line-length=80"],
  "python.linting.pycodestyleEnabled": true,
  "python.linting.pylintEnabled": false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer the line to be very long, you can use a comment to tell flake8 to ignore the fact that the line is long by writing `# noqa: E501` at the end of the line.

Black currently does not split strings, there is an [open issue](https://github.com/psf/black/issues/182) for this on their github.

Comment: I mean I'd prefer it to pass and to have a tool/method that could format it for me. Is there nothing out there that you know of that can limit string length?

Comment: Thanks for the ignore long lines tip. That will have to suffice for now, cheers

Comment: I don't know of any good generic string splitters; I assume it is a hard problem based on the age and activity on that issue. Depending on the contents and usage of the strings, this may be a good IDE/editor question, since this may be solved in this particular case by a regex or macro to do something naive like `insert "\"\\\n\"" every 60 characters`.